# "Main" has already been declared in the current scope

Tags: c++

I have a source file where is used a namespace called: ::main and this header is included in order to build my process in main.cpp.
When I compiled the code I received the following error:
    ***"main" has already been declared in the current scope***
The valid solution will be to exlude the file from current process, but this is not an option.
I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Compiler is probabbly mixing it with function and namespace

Comment: @Armin: It is indeed. C++ does not allow that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program

```
namespace main{}
int main(){}
```

is not valid C++.

You are not allowed to have a namespace called `main` in the same translation unit as the function `main`. (The same applies to any function at global scope, not just `main`.)

C++ does not allow that (a redeclaration of a symbol is not allowed), and the compiler will issue a diagnostic, such as the one that you observe.